# How do I modify a registry value during uninstall (Basic MSI project)

Tags: windows-installer, registry, installshield, uninstallation

I have a registry value that I set to `1` during installation. What I want to achieve is that during uninstall this value should be set to `0` instead of being removed.

How do I get about doing this?

I am using Installshield 2011 and the project is a Basic MSI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support this directly. You will have to use a custom action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into making a custom action :)

Answer (score 2):

It is true that Windows Installer doesn't support creating/setting registry values during an uninstall.  Strange, isn't it?

I don't know what registry value you are setting, but the install could be made simpler ( no custom action ) if you are able to modify the application to accept the lack of the registry value as equivilant to 0.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. This might be the solution I end up with, should making the custom action cause troubles.

Yes, it is indeed strange that it isn't supported.

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: You are correct, buddy - and it is done on my behalf at least :)
I was actually not aware of the feature - so much for my perception skills :)
Happy holidays :)

Comment: Hi all,

I have tried to execute an exe via custom action during uninstall process. But, it also results the same. It executes the piece of code but it does not affect the Registry Editor's value. Attaching the Stackoverflow thread for your reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060562/modify-registry-value-during-uninstalling-msi-build-in-windows

Please let me know if there are any possibilities available.