# Modify registry value during uninstalling MSI build in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, regedit

We have tried to modify the proxy value which is present in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings** during the uninstall process in windows machine (32-bit). We are able to get the value but not able to modify it. We have tried in multiple methods like Async, Threading, CMD method, Created new exe & tried to execute it. But, none of the methods have modified the value. Is there any other way to modify the value?

```
string inetPath = @"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
RegistryKey inetSubkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(internetSettingsSubkeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
string keyName = inetSubkey.Name;               
string valueName1 = "ProxyEnable";
string value = "0";
RegistryValueKind dataType = RegistryValueKind.DWord;
Registry.SetValue(keyName, valueName1, value, dataType);
```

I need to modify the ProxyEnable during the uninstall process of MSI application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registry Key not writing, no error messages C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71496484/registry-key-not-writing-no-error-messages-c-sharp)

Comment: I have tried but this only needs to be updated in Internet settings during uninstalling process.

Comment: Is your MSI installed per-user or per-machine? (for all users)

Comment: It is for all the users in the machine.

Comment: the program that change the registry value is running with the current user account or another account like admin or system account ?

Comment: @Christophe, The application is running only in Admin account. We cannot uninstall the application without the admin permission i.e.) it will be asking for admin credentials.

Comment: If you run the program with your admin account, you will change the registry value in HKEY_USERS\<YOUR SID>\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings. 
If you run the program with SYSTEM account, you will change the registry value in HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER is for the user who is currently logged on. 
If you need to find the HKEY_USERS\<currently logged on user SID>, this is the one that contains a subkey "Volatile Environment"

Comment: Thanks, @Christophe. I have checked the proxy which is set only in current user. I able to change the value of the ProxyEnable item with the normal flow. But, I need to change it only when the MSI build is Uninstalling stage. we have an event beforeuninstall, afteruninstall. When I tried to change the value from that event, I'm unable to make it. Please let me know if there is any specific reason.

Comment: @Christophe, I have fixed the issue by calling the reset proxy functions.